# How to highlight a 2D section of a 3D plot?

Tags: plotting

From the following 3D plot

```
    p1 = Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
p2 = RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion[
      ImplicitRegion[{x - y == 0}, {x, y, z}]], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.3]], Mesh -> None, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[LightBlue, Thin]];
Show[p1, p2, AxesLabel -> {"F", "C", "time"}]
```

how can one *highlight* a 2D slice as shown by blue dash below?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
p1 = Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
p2 = RegionPlot3D[
   DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[{x - y == 0}, {x, y, z}]], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.3]], Mesh -> None, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[LightBlue, Thin]];
p3 = Graphics3D[{Dashed, Blue, Thick, 
    Line[{{{0.5, 0, 0}, {0.5, 0.5, Sin[0.5^2]}}, {{0.5, 0.5, 
        Sin[0.5^2]}, {0.5, 0.5, 1}}}]}];
Show[p1, p2, p3, AxesLabel -> {"F", "C", "time"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel Huber, you are amazing!

Comment: Just a minor point @Daniel Huber. In a similar situation, I have Sqrt[x y] instead of Sin[x y]. I tried this replacement of Sin by Sqrt, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The approximation by a straight line from {0,0.5} to {0.5,0.5} is good enough for Sin, but not for Sqrt. In this case you must create an additional "ParametricPlot" for this curve.

Answer (score 3):

The slice corresponds to a simple relation between x and y, in this case, x=y. So you can substitute that and use Plot:

```
Plot[Sin[x y] /. y -> x, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Other slices will have different relation between x and y, and can be handled the same way.

If you prefer the horizontal axis to correspond to distance along the slice instead of along the x axis, you could use ParametericPlot instead.

To show this section on the 3D plot, use ParametricPlot3D:

```
Show[
 Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}],
 ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x, y, Sin[x y]} /. y -> x], {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Black]
 ]
```

[image]

To show x=0.5 plane up to the intersection with x=y plane, combine this with your plot:

```
With[{X = 0.5},
 Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[{X, y, Sin[X y]}, {y, 0, X}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
  Graphics3D[{Blue, Thick, HalfLine[{X, X, Sin[X^2]}, {0, 0, 1}]}],
  PlotRange -> All
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: You can add the ParametricPlot3D to your plot. I may be confused by what slice you mean -- the plot with x=y follows the light blue slice plane of your Region plot. The dashed blue curve you show isn't on the surface. Do you mean to indicate a plane with constant x instead of x=y? If so, you could change the 1st coordinate in ParametricPlot3D to be,  e.g., 0.5, or whatever value used for the dashed curve. Does that give what you want?